# Reordenar elementos de uma pesquisa na tela

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, django

tenho uma aplicação em django e preciso reordenar os elementos da tela quando o usuario decidir ordenar por data, popularidade, etc..

Eu não gostaria de submeter uma nova pesquisa a cada vez que o usuario selecione um filtro, acredito que a melhor maneira seria apenas reordenar os elementos já carregados, talvez usando jquery, json.

Não encontrei nenhum material que pudesse me ajudar, teriam alguma dica sobre como implementar ou alguma recomendação de site?

Comment: Apresente um exemplo da tabela e do json... como você está populando ela?

Comment: Ainda não fiz, hj a aplicação apenas busca os dados no banco, popula um `dict` e exibe na tela.

Answer (score 0):

Use uma lib de tabela dinâmica por exemplo: DataTables, Handsontable. Elas irão fazer esse trabalho de ordenar já com os dados presente me tela.

Tem alguns bons tutoriais:

https://dev.to/codeshard/datatables-and-django-finally-with-ajax